# Boost::asio in Rcpp : is it possible?

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

I am new in Rcpp and I would like to know if there is a possibility to move inside Rcpp the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SimpleSerial.h"
using namespace std;`
using namespace boost;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
try {

    SimpleSerial serial("COM5",9600);

    serial.writeString("Hello world\r\n");

    cout<<"Received : "<<serial.readLine()<<" : end"<<endl;

} catch(boost::system::system_error& e)
{
    cout<<"Error: "<<e.what()<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

The code comes from the examples of boost and is succesfully compiled under MinGW64 with the commands:

```
g++ -O2 -c main.cpp -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501
g++ -o simple.exe main.o -s -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -lboost_system
```

My purpose is to make a function that send and receive the two strings to the COM port inside R. Any suggestions where to start in Rcpp ? Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can "in theory"--you just have to learn how to build a package which includes header and libraries as Boost Asio requires linking. So "in practice" this may be a little more involved.  Which is one of the reasons we keep the BH package simpler: no linking...

Comment: Wonderful. I am just studyng your examples on these subject. If I well understood, the Rcpp (or the BH package) should take care of the best way to compile depending of the OS in use. Am I wrong ? Doing that R can have a direct control of a serial port. Correct ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No you misunderstood. You have much more work to do because Boost Asio requires more pieces: supplied in a library you need to link. More work also because your users need it.  Still doable, but all more work.